# QJackCtl - Alsa Unknown driver

Tags: alsa, jack

Here's my problem :

I just have installed QJackCtl on my Ubuntu 12.04 and when I start Jack I got this issue :

```
12:01:22.769 /usr/local/bin/jackd -dalsa -dhw:0 -r44100 -p1024 -n3 -i1 -o2
Cannot connect to server socket err = Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Unknown driver "alsa"
```

If anyone knows the solution It would help me a lot !

Comment: have you tried starting the application you need it for before starting jack server?

Comment: Yes I have , and it change nothing .

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you don't have the alsa-devel package installed, so when you compiled jackdmp it couldn't link to alsa.

Install that and recompile and I'm sure it'll work